# Getting class values to correspond in each of 5 Landsat thematic maps processed using Supervised Classification in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, imagery, landsat

I have used Supervised Classification (Maximum Liklihood) to produce thematic maps from Landsat imagery in ArcMap for the years 2004, 2006, 2009, 2013, 2015. I have produced 9 land-use classes. I now want to examine 'from to' change between years, but the class values in each map vary.

How do I get the class values to correspond in each of the maps?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Con()](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/conditional-evaluation-with-con.htm) function in raster calculator to change the cell values of each class to the corresponding cell values of the correct class.

However, since the order of the 9 classes are different in each image, you need first to change the cell values to a scale not in the range of 1-9, but to some unique number for each class.

Why you need to do this is because if ,for example, the class 1 should be class 3, and class 3 should be class 1, if you wrote `con("raster2004"=1,3,"raster2004")` in raster calculator, you will change the pixel value 1 to 3, but when you need to correct the pixel value 3 to 1 using the same method `con("raster2004"=3,1,"raster2004")`, this time the class 3 includes also class 1 (two classes). That is why you need to convert the pixel values to a scale not in the range 1-9 to avoid merging classes by mistake.